# Making a criss crossing track suitable for temporal display in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I have digitised a track in QGIS from Maps.me screen shots but when displayed it is confusing as it crosses and backtracks several times.

I would like to display the track in short segments in Temporal as an animation but have had no success.

I tried recording the track in short segments as a line string with a date time field but there was no opportunity to add a time when each segment was saved so consequently no time for Temporal to work on.

If it is not possible to digitise with time I wondered if it would be possible to extract the coordinates from my original file and add them to a csv with a date field?  However I can't find a way of extracting the coordinates.

I am competent with tracks, points and loading via csv but have very limited knowledge of Python.

I have formatted data as shown by Kasper but when I try to Add Layer- txt file it shows 2 symbols before the wkt and there is no track on map and an error triangle in Layers saying Unavailable layer!
[image: Loading data]

Screen shot of data in Notepad.
[image: Data in Notepad]

Extra characters were caused by incorrect date, now corrected.  Still have error I don't understand.
[image: Error in Layers]
[image: Dialog displayed when Error clicked]

link to data file [Data as loaded](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ap9tfttWLwAF6VFyDe75iImcU5qd?e=bMufUr)

Sorry missed your comment Kasper, no PW added but try this link [Same file different location](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ko6a4nm3caphts/wkt2.txt?dl=0)

Comment: I went to Create Layer, New Spatialite Layer, specified name/location, Geometry type-Linestring, New Field-Date,Add to fields list.  However it never asked me to add date when creating the geometry.  I have since exported original the track as a kml and extracted coordinates in Notepad++.  I then used Libra Write & Calc to format and add date, saved as csv.  This works as an animation but gives me a series of points rather than lines, not as elegant as I'd hoped

Comment: I was hoping to have small segments that appear along the animation.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but I've not come across WKT Linestring before and have no idea how to edit such a beast.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow, thank you.

Comment: Are you fine with interpolated DateTimes for the segments? For this you would just need lines, startdatetimes and enddatetimes.

Comment: for the field name issue probably a hidden character in your file ? Beware: your date format is incorrect, it has no month nor day

Comment: I've checked for hidden characters in Notepad, win and Text Editor, Ubuntu, neither show any extra characters.  Is there a preferable way of checking?  I've had so many attempts to get data into format I didn't notice missing month-day, back to drawing board. Characters are possibly caused by incorrect date format?

Comment: The DBox file you shared has quotes (") at the begining and end of line, you need to remove them and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can format your .csv like the following:

```
wkt;date
LINESTRING(0 0,0 1);2022-01-01 13:00:00
LINESTRING(0 1,0 2);2022-01-01 14:00:00
LINESTRING(0 2,0 3);2022-01-01 15:00:00
LINESTRING(0 3,0 4);2022-01-01 16:00:00
LINESTRING(0 4,0 5);2022-01-01 17:00:00
LINESTRING(0 5,0 6);2022-01-01 18:00:00
LINESTRING(0 6,0 7);2022-01-01 19:00:00
```

Then import as delimited text file, geometry should be `WKT`, data field as `Date & Time`

If you load it as such, it will display all the small Lines as a continous line:
[image]

If you animate that layer based on the `date` field, you get each item displayed one by one (depending on the animation settings and the time granularity in the source data):

[image]

Comment: Clear now, just need to get data into required format.

Comment: Added link to data file at end of question.

Comment: Dded Dropbox link.